# Using Views as a report in a custom module

Tags: views, routes, log-messages

I'm new-ish to module development. I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

I have a custom module that I think would benefit from a report. The report should show up in the admin reports menu. (I already know how to use hook_menu to display "Hello world!" as a report in the reports menu.)

It seems to me that the easiest way to compile the data for the report would be to use Views. But where do I go from here? How do I programatically use a View as one of the reports my module provides? (Or am I wrong in assuming that this can be done or is a good way of doing things?)

To be clear: I am not talking about my module providing a default view that shows up in the views menu, but using the data from a View as a report.

What I want is the same result as [this idea](https://drupal.org/node/1273306), but programatically in my module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[views_get_view_result](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7) is the API you should use to query an existing View and process the results in your module.